# What is the differance between CURL, WGET and PHP Cronjob

Tags: php, curl, cron, wget

I am trying to create a cronjob and I don't know what is the difference between those lines, ans which one I am supposed to use to make the Cronjob work correctly.

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php5.5 /website/cron.php
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/curl /website/cron.php
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/wget /website/cron.php
```

Now I need to know which one works, I am sure that my server has the CURL and WGET installed by using the commande line:

```
whereis wget
whereis curl
```

But when I tried creating a simple php file to send me emails only this code worked for me:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php5.5 /website/cron.php
```

So what to do?

Comment: What I want is knowing the difference between them, I search the whole web but find nothing

Comment: [php on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) | [curl on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl) | [wget on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) | [cron on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Now the real question is what exactly did you search for and where?

Comment: I have a third party script installed on my host, and I have in their instruction a Corn job section, where I am asked to create a Corn job using WGET or CURL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CURL

curl  is  a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the
supported protocols

sytax is

```
curl [oprions] URL
```

The  URL  syntax is protocol-dependent. You'll find a detailed descrip‐
       tion in RFC 3986.

similar is the case with wget

```
wget [options] URL
```

Both will submit request to weserver's php module  via HTTP , which inturn calls php complier only . for them to use in cron cron.php must be in such location that can be requested via HTTP

like

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/curl http://web-url/cron.php
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://web-url/cron.php
```

while

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php5.5 /website/cron.php
```

can be used simply to run a php script local avaiable on servrer

Comment: That was so helpful

Answer (score 1):

`curl` and `wget` are supposed to send a http request(like downloading files/ post data etc.)

`cron.php` is a php file. You should always use php (whatever version) to execute it.

That's why only `0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php5.5 /website/cron.php` worked.

If you really want to use `curl` or `wget`, here is an example:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://youwebsite.com/cron.php &>/dev/null
```